# The return type 'Set<GameScreen>' isn't a 'Widget'. Flutter Navigation

Tags: flutter

In `home.dart` I call a navigation function inside an Elevated Button

```
 onPressed: (){
  Navigator.of(context).push(
     MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context)=>{
                return const GameScreen();
          }
  ));
 },
```

Which will navigate to GameScreen.

`game_screen.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GameScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.white,);
  }
}
```

However I get the red squiggly lines under the navigation function saying

```
The return type "Set<GameScreen>" isn't a "Widget", as required by the closure's context.
```

Why is this giving me an error and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused with typescript, the method syntax is not `() => {...}`, this would return a `Set` of `...`

Do this instead `() {...}` (runs `...`):

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return const GameScreen();
      }
 ));
},
```

Or this `() => ...` (returns `...`):

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => const GameScreen(),
  ));
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you're returning a `Set<Widget>`

The problem is how you're using the arrow operator `=>`, you cannot use `{}` and the `return` keyword with the arrow operator.

The `=>` operator already works like a `return`. And in your case the `{}` is being interpreted like a Set literal.

Try this instead:

```
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => const GameScreen();
));
```

Or this:

```
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) {
   return const GameScreen();
  }
));
```

Comment: Ah got it! Thanks